# Google Drive API - Downloading a file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Using a oauth2 connection I have a **working script** (listing documents from Google Drive), I only need to **add a download/export function**.

*Note: access_token / refresh_token are already set (different script)*

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php');
require_once('vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Drive.php');

session_start();

$client_id = '<client_id>';
$client_secret = '<client_secret>';
$redirect_uri = '<redirect_uri>';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType('offline'); // Gets us our refreshtoken
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

 ## Step 1: Set token ##

       $array = array(
           'access_token'    => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', //set access token
           'token_type'      => 'Bearer',
           'expires_in'      => 0,
           'created'         => 0,
           'refresh_token'   => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', //set refresh token
       );

       $_SESSION['token'] = $array;

    ## Step 2: If token is active, list documents ##

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

          // Get the API client and construct the service object.

            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

              // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
              $optParams = array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
                'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
              );
              $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

              if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
                print "No files found.\n";
              } else {
                print "Files:\n";
                foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
                  printf("%s (%s)\n<br>", $file->getName(), $file->getId());

                }
              }

      }
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to create a direct download link (for non public files). I have found the following documentation but I'm lost on how I can apply this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

The PHP example from "manage-downloads" results in an error:

> Undefined variable: driveService in ... my_drive_script.php

Simply adding a link works, but only for *shared* documents (or if I'm logged in under the same user).

```
$fileid = $file->getId();
printf("<a href='https://docs.google.com/document/d/$fileid/export?format=doc'>Download doc</a>");
```

I have used the link format from http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/

**It should be possible to download non public files, right?**

Comment: Hey Steve, deleted my previous answer as it wasn't necessary since you added further info. I'll report if I can get to the bottom of this and help you out, I wish you good luck in solving this

Comment: Thanks tcsh, I have updated my post again, feel that the solution is getting closer :)